# Is StringBuilder really faster than Aggreggate?

Tags: c#, string

```
        string c = tmpArr[0].Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, m) => current + (m.Name + " "));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Mobile m in tmpArr[0])
            sb.Append(m.Name + " ");

        sb.ToString();
```

which of those two is faster? aggregate certainly is cleaner, but is it fast or is it the same as doing

```
foreach(Mobile m in tmpArr[0])
    c += m.Name + " ";
```

what I really would like to do is something like `string.Join(",",tmpArr[0])`, but I don't want it to concat their ToString values, just their Names, how would I do that best?

my problem with not using `string.Join` is I would actually have to do something like this:

```
        string separator = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Mobile m in tmpArr[0])
        {
            separator = ", ";
            sb.Append(separator + m.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Did you test? What did your results dictate?

Comment: How many elements do you expect? If it isn't a lot then speed won't matter as much as cleanliness of code. Figure out your worst case scenario in terms of size, measure the results, decide what trade offs are acceptable.

Comment: -1, Furthermore, does it even matter? Unless you've got 10-20,000 names you're concatenating, I doubt you'll notice a difference.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment that’s unfair. Writing correct micro-benchmarks is hellishly difficult – as evidenced by the fact that most that are posted here have serious flaws. Asking this question is very justified.

Comment: @sixlettervariables It does matter. What do you care? Furthermore, what was your reason for the downvote?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I agree the question in itself is justified (I never mentioned that it wasn't), not providing some result of inspection done personally, however, is not.

Comment: Wasn't a well worded question, on top of no effort to test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I don't want it to concat their ToString values, just their Names, how would I do that best?

```
string.Join(",",tmpArr[0].Select(t => t.Name).ToArray())
```

But most of the time [**It. Just. Doesn't. Matter!**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

Comment: ToArray isn't necessary in .net 4. An overload takes an IEnumerable<string>

Comment: @Alex Ford It's 2014 so I guess it's fine that an answer is .NET 4 and above.

Answer (score 14):

If you append strings in a loop (`c += m.Name + " ";`) you are causing lots of intermediate strings to be created; this causes "telescopic" memory usage, and puts extra load on GC. Aggregate, mixed with the fluent-API of StringBuilder can help here - but as would looping with StringBuilder. It isn't Aggregate that is important: it is ***not creating lots of intermediate strings***.

For example, I would use:

```
foreach (Mobile m in tmpArr[0])
        sb.Append(m.Name).Append(" ");
```

even fewer ;p

And for a similar example using StringBuilder in Aggregate:

```
string c = tmpArr[0].Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
    (current, m) => current.Append(m.Name).Append(" ")).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Aggregate` itself is not the problem. The problem is you are concatenating strings in a loop. When you concatenate two strings with `+` operator, a new place must be allocated in memory and the two strings are copied into it. So if you use the `+` five times, you actually create five new strings. That's why you should use `StringBuilder` or `Join` which avoid this.

If you want to use `Join` along with linq for better readability, you still can, just don't use `Aggregate` but something like `Select` and `ToArray`.

Answer (score 1):

As string is Immutable, add operation has performance cost. This is what the StringBuilder is mainly designed for, it acts like "Mutable" String. I haven't done much benchmarking for the speed, but for memory optimizations StringBuilder is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

`Aggregate` runs an anonymous method against each item in the `IEnumerable`. This method is passed to the System-defined `Func<>` delegate which returns an out parameter.

It's basically like running a function that does the appending as many times.

So allocation/deallocation on the stack for the method calls etc certainly has more overhead than running a simple `for`/`foreach` loop

So, in my opinion the **second method** would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
string joined = string.Join(",", myItems.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());
```